# Why does my axis CSS differ depending on whether I use an exernal CCS file or not (D3.js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to style my axis with D3 without using external CSS files for things such as the circles, axis etc. The reason is I want to export the SVG from the browser, which doesn't get the css edits from an external file.

However when I apply the same code on D3 and the external css file, I get different results.
I don't understand why the following happens:

```
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
}
```

From the above code in my external ccs file, the following is created:
http://puu.sh/8iScH.png

```
.style({"fill": "none", "stroke": "#000"})
```

By using .style() I cannot achieve the same look, this is the result:
http://puu.sh/8iS6x.png

Why do they differ when I'm using the same code?

***EDIT***
I'm not changing axis PATH and axis LINE when using D3. My actual question is, how can I changes .axis path and .axis line with d3's .style()?

Comment: seems like your external css is not applied.

Comment: What are you calling `.style()` on?

Comment: This little tool may be of help [SVG Crowbar](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/)

Comment: @ChristopherHackett I already tried using Crowbar.js, but it only works on chrome and opera at the moment, since it uses the `download` attribute, which IE and Safari don't support yet.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm calling style here: `SVG.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").style(...)`

Comment: I can get past this issue using jQuery to edit the CSS. But I don't know if this is a good way to do it?

Comment: You're applying the style to the wrong elements. You need to select exactly what you have in the CSS, e.g. `svg.selectAll("path.axis").style(...)`.